# Require secret key using google Oauth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I have a Web application using Google and Facebook signin.

I want to require the authentification by adding the secret key, so in the client side  I can connect just using my own application and not any other application.

I did that in Facebook by adding the appsecret-proof parameter, enable

[image: this]

How I can do the same using google?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a new set of "Web Credentials" for your application via https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials and the client secret would be available there.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

The above describes how Google Oauth works and its configurations.